# How to create table without breaking row? (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this bootstrap snippet:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12">Project Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jan</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Feb</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Mar</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Apr</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">May</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jun</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jul</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Aug</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Sep</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Okt</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Nov</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Dec</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12">Project #1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="col-xs-1">10</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">20</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">30</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">40</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">50</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">60</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">70</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">80</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">90</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">100</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">110</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">120</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it creates this table:

[image]

Everything looks good on the Desktop, but when I watch it on mobile or tablet it breaks:

[image]

Is it possible to create it without breaking? (version with tables does not fit)

Comment: If nothing else you can have it scroll.

Comment: quick fix: make your text smaller for mobile, long fix: you need a different layout for mobile.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes, I think so. How I can do that properly in my case?

Comment: If you check my answer below, it will automatically add a scroll on narrow devices

Comment: And here comes the RWD. Refactor your divs into a table and just follow the example: https://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `min-width` on the container like this:

```css
.container {
  min-width: 630px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12">Project Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jan</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Feb</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Mar</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Apr</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">May</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jun</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jul</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Aug</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Sep</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Okt</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Nov</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Dec</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12">Project #1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="col-xs-1">10</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">20</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">30</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">40</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">50</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">60</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">70</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">80</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">90</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">100</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">110</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">120</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @K.Daniek: what do you mean?

Comment: I can not change .`container`,  because it involves a lot of important elements

Comment: Its said that the simplest solutions are best, but not in this case. We got 21 century and a method called RWD.

Comment: @MaxGabderakhmanov use any other class name, for example rename it to `table-container`

Answer (score 0):

This approach can work for narrow viewports:

```
[class^="col-"] {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can wrap it into `@media` for x-small screens only.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the elements wrapping the breaking `div`s to `display: flex`, which will by default display them in one row instead of breaking:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 flex">
            <div class="col-xs-12">Project Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 flex">
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jan</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Feb</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Mar</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Apr</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">May</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jun</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jul</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Aug</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Sep</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Okt</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Nov</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Dec</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 flex">
            <div class="col-xs-12">Project #1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 flex">
            <div class="col-xs-1">10</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">20</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">30</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">40</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">50</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">60</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">70</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">80</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">90</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">100</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">110</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">120</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```